# How do I add text to an HTML element in Dart?

Tags: dart

I would like to add some text to an element in the DOM. How do I do this in Dart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Element.text](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_html/Element.html#text) to set the text content of the element or [Element.appendText](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_html/Element.html#appendText) to add a text after the last child of the element :

```dart
import 'dart:html';

main() {
  var elem = new DivElement();
  // replace content with the text
  elem.text = "the text";
  // add a text after the last child of this element
  elem.appendText("the text");
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I deleted my (very) outdated answer.

Answer (score 0):

New syntax of previous answer:

```
import 'dart:html';
main() {
  var elem = new DivElement();
  elem.appendText("the text");
}
```

There is new import style and method `appendText(String text)` for adding the specified text after the last child.